# Transaction Mode in SQL

Tags: sql, transactions, ansi-sql

I was reading through the [BNF grammar](https://ronsavage.github.io/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#start%20transaction%20statement) for transaction statements and saw that transaction modes can be specified directly in the `START TRANSACTION` statement. Is there a difference in specifying transaction modes in `START TRANSACTION` vs `SET TRANSACTION` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference. The `SET TRANSACTION` setting only affects the single next
transaction to be started.

Use `SET SESSION` to set the default for the session's transactions.

Comment: So does specifying transaction modes in the START TRANSACTION statement persist to future statements somehow? I say that because you specified that SET TRANSACTION only affects the next transaction to specifying in START TRANSACTION is somehow different?

Comment: No, START TRANSACTION works in the same way, just that transaction is affected.

Comment: So there really isn't much a difference at all? Since SET TRANSACTION occurs at the beginning of the transaction, it's almost like that statement is optional?

Comment: You could say that. SET SESSION makes much more sense.